# String format like a table in a loop swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, string-formatting

I have this problem and all possible solutions I'm looking for online hasn't helped me. Is there a way to make a table like in a string format?

What I'm expecting the output will be like this for a string:

```
Category
 ITEM1     QTY     PRICE      TOTAL
 ITEM2     QTY     PRICE      TOTAL
```

but my output code is like this:

```
Category
 ITEM1         QTY     PRICE      TOTAL
 ITEM2      QTY      PRICE      TOTAL

Category
 ITEM1             QTY       PRICE        TOTAL
 ITEM2       QTY        PRICE      TOTAL
```

I figured out something that the item string length is the cost why they are not aligned formally in my format, but is there a way on how to solve this issue? I'm totally new in swift.

here is my code:

```
for category in self.categoryList {
        sentence += "Category: \(category)\n"
        for items in self.productList {
            if category == items.category {
                grandTotal += Double(items.qty)! * Double(items.price)!
                let total: Double = Double(items.qty)! * Double(items.price)!
                let item = (items.item as NSString).utf8String
                let qty  = (items.qty as NSString).utf8String
                let price = (items.price as NSString).utf8String
                sentence += String(format: "%-10s%20s%15s%15.02f\n", item!, qty!, price!, total)
            }
        }
        sentence += "\n\n"
        grandTotal = 0
    }

    lblData.text = sentence
```

Comment: Can't you use html tags in your string for formatting?

Comment: can I actually do that inside of string? and how?

Comment: check https://medium.com/swift2go/swift-how-to-convert-html-using-nsattributedstring-8c6ffeb7046f

Comment: A non string solution is to use one UILabel per column

Comment: What about using a `UITableView` with a custom cell that has 4 labels? This looks like a perfect use case for that.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks I already think about that and work on it, but I want them to store in label and loop it on the string appending them.

Comment: @kimnicolesabordo But _why_? I think the reason why the current code is not working is because the font is not a monospace font. Just use a `UITableView` and it will save you a _lot_ of trouble, both now and in the future.

Comment: @Sweeper indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could pad your strings to a defined length:

```
let elements = ["ITEM1", "QTY", "PRICE", "TOTAL"]

// without padding
var sentence = ""
for e in elements {
    if !sentence.isEmpty {
        sentence += " "
    }
    sentence += e
}

print(sentence)
// prints "ITEM1 QTY PRICE TOTAL"

// with padding
sentence = ""
for e in elements {
    sentence += e.padding(toLength: 10, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
}

print(sentence)
// prints "ITEM1     QTY       PRICE     TOTAL     "
```

Or in a shorter form:

```
// without padding
var sentence = elements.joined(separator: " ")
print(sentence)

// with padding
sentence = elements.map({$0.padding(toLength: 10, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)}).joined(separator: " ")
print(sentence)
```